# Exercise 8.2-b from Czes Kosniowski's A First Course In Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading the book Czes Kosniowski's A First Course In Algebraic Topology and i can't solve the exercise:

---

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by: $U \in \mathscr{F}$ if and only if for each $s \in U$ there is a $t>s$ such that $[s,t] \subseteq U$. Prove that $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{F})$ is Haudorff.

---

Someone can help me to solve this question or give me some hint? I guess the the proof follow by definition of Hausdorff space

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is a Euclidean open set in $\Bbb R$ it is open for $\mathscr{F}$ too: let $s \in U$, then for some $r>0$ we have $(x-r,x+r) \subseteq U$. But then $[s,s+\frac{r}{2}] \subseteq U$ and we can use $t=s+\frac{r}{2}>s$ to see that $U \in \mathscr{F}$.

As the Euclidean topology is Hausdorff, the even larger $\mathscr{F}$ also is.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq y$. We can assume that $x<y$. Bearing in mind the definition of a Hausdorff space, what can we say about $[x,y)$ and $[y,\infty)$?